# php extract() usage and purpose

Tags: php

I (think) I understand the function of php's extract() function. However, I was reading some code and I saw something like this:

```
extract(['a' => '', 'b' => '', 'c' => 1, 'd' => 0]);
```

My questions:

1: Is this functionally different from:

```
$a = ''; $b = ''; $c = 1; $d = 0;
```

2: What are the reasons for variable declaration/assignment using extract()?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using it, as you don't always have control about what comes from the array (if its dynamically generated or loaded). Its better to just use array-indexes (imo). But in the end, extracting variables from arrays is pretty much the same as declaring them, but I see no reason why you would want to declare them that way to begin with (if thats the sole purpose).

Comment: @WillParky93, from the manual: 'do not use extract on untrusted data'.

Comment: Just to reiterate the above - *please* don't use `extract` on user provided data. You're basically just re-implementing `register_globals`, which was disabled by default more than 15 years ago because it was a terrible idea.

Comment: @Progrock *starts sweating intensely* I guess I've got a busy week ahead of me.

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/VSbh5/vld#output and https://3v4l.org/WiMZe/vld#output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Is this functionally different from...*

No both lines of code are equivalent. `extract` returns values where the key is set to the variable name and the value is what that variable equals, which is depicted in each line of code making them functionally equivalent.

*What are the reasons for variable declaration/assignment using extract()?*

A reasonable use case would be using `extract` on a function that returns an array of values with known keys. Doing this saves you time in writing a line of declaration for each stored value. I say known keys because although using unknown keys is possible through using [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`variable variables`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), you start to enter a realm of questionable coding techniques by doing this.

Within the documentation of [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) it states, "Do not use extract() on untrusted data...", which include user inputted data which may have been maliciously altered. Though this means using `extract` on $_POST is improper for a public version, there is nothing functionally wrong with doing this for testing or a personal project where you can guarantee the values of the $_POST are as expected.

Keep in mind that there is a level of ambiguity when using `extract` and if your program ever need be maintained at a later date, understanding what an `extract` statement is returning or finding the origin of variables that came from an extract may be difficult. `extract` has its uses within programs, but it should be accompanied with comments outlining what it is doing, to make future reference more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Purpose. 
1. It could be used as a version of list(). But in a case of extract() you don't need to take care about an order of the vars.
Also, the vars that was extracted from array belong to the particular scope.
In a case of usage with the db you can be sure the var exists

```
function foo($db){
    $hdl =  $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM test.first");
    $hdl->execute();
    $resultArray = $hdl->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    extract($resultArray,EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "wddx");
    echo $id . "<br>";
    echo $name . "<br>";
    echo $email . "<br>";
}
```

2.pass variable into the Views when you are using MVC

```
//View.php
class View {
    function render($filename = null) {
        if ($filename !== null) {
            $this->filename = $filename;
        }
        unset($filename);
        extract($this->variables);
        ob_start();
        $this->returned = include($this->dir . $this->filename);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}

//test.php
$view = new View;
$view->filename = 'test.phtml';
$view->dir = './';
$view->variables = array('test' => 'tset');
echo $view->render('test.phtml');
var_dump($view->returned);

//test.phtml
<?php echo $test; ?>
```

Comment: Using extract is useful for convenience in views, `<?= $foo ?>` is tidier than `<?= $this->foo ?>` or `<?= $array['foo'] ?>`.  My only worry is if you extract without references, you might end up copying/doubling your data.

Comment: Please read docs for extract(). there some flags and modes to deal with doubling and overwriting